# NHibernate comparison constraint to a coalesced date

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover, nhibernate-criteria

There is a great Q/A to prefacing this question here:
[NHibernate COALESCE issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364036/nhibernate-coalesce-issue)

I need to be able to compare a date object to a date value from within an inner join. The unfamiliar territory here has been the implementation of this COALESCE along with the date LT constraint

Here is my current SQL query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Sites.*
FROM Sites
 INNER JOIN Sites_WF_Info
       ON Site_Key = SiteWFInfo_Site_Key
       AND SiteWFInfo_Effective_Date <= @today
       AND @today <= SiteWFInfo_End_Date
 INNER JOIN Profit_Centers
       ON Site_Key = ProfCtr_Site_Key
       AND ProfCtr_Open_Date <= @today
       AND @today < Coalesce(ProfCtr_Close_Date, '6/6/2079')
```

What I would like to know is how to go about using a constant in place of the ExpenseReport.PeriodFrom property ==> left.

Ideally, I would like to set left/right

```
// DateTime effDate is passed in
var left = Projections.Property<DateTime>(effDate);
var right = Projects.SqlFunction("COALESCE",
            NHibernateUtil.DateTime,
            Projections.Constant(DateTime.Parse("6/6/2079").Date, NHibernateUtil.DateTime),
            Projections.Property<ProfitCenter>(pc => pc.CloseDate));
```

Then, when the restriction is invoked

```
var restriction = Restrictions.LtProperty(left, right);
```

So that when I build the QueryOver<> I can substitute this **restriction** object for one of the Where clauses

```
var foo = CurrentSession().QueryOver<Site>(() => sa)
    .Inner.JoinQueryOver<ProfitCenter>(() => pca)
    .Where(restriction)
```

---

**THE FINAL ANSWER**

This required the introduction of a new 'flattened' domain 'ResultModel' (SiteWithWindowsTimezoneId) so that I could return a more specific model from my query and avoid lazy loading all the other stuff that is currently associated with Site. This new query style has turned a 16+ sql query method down to a single query. The savings was worth the time. Thanks again for your help. I hope that this gist is helpful to someone in the future.

```
SiteWorkforceInfo swia = null;
SiteWorkforceConfig swcfg = null;
ProfitCenter pca = null;
Site sa = null;
SiteWithWindowsTimezoneId siteResult = null;

var leftProfCloseDate = Projections.Constant(effectiveDate);
var rightProfCloseDate = Projections.SqlFunction("COALESCE", 
    NHibernateUtil.DateTime, 
    Projections.Property<ProfitCenter>(pc => pc.CloseDate),
    Projections.Constant(DateTime.Parse("6/6/2079").Date, NHibernateUtil.DateTime)
);

var profCloseDateRestriction = Restrictions.LtProperty(leftProfCloseDate, rightProfCloseDate);

var activeSites = CurrentSession().QueryOver<SiteWorkforceInfo>(() => swia)
    .Inner.JoinQueryOver<Site>(() => swia.Site, () => sa)
    .Left.JoinQueryOver<SiteWorkforceConfig>(() => sa.SiteWFConfig, () => swcfg)
    .Inner.JoinQueryOver<ProfitCenter>(() => sa.ProfitCenters, () => pca)
    .Where(() => swia.EffectiveDate <= effectiveDate)
    .Where(() => effectiveDate <= swia.EndDate)
    .Where(() => pca.OpenDate <= effectiveDate)
    .Where(profCloseDateRestriction)
    .Where(() => swia.TimeCaptureRule > 0)
    .SelectList(
        list => list
            .Select(() => sa.Key).WithAlias(() => siteResult.Key)
            .Select(() => sa.Id).WithAlias(() => siteResult.Id)
            .Select(() => sa.IdFormatted).WithAlias(() => siteResult.IdFormatted)
            .Select(() => sa.Description).WithAlias(() => siteResult.Description)
            .Select(() => swcfg.WindowsTimezoneId).WithAlias(() => siteResult.WindowsTimezoneId)
                )
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<SiteWithWindowsTimezoneId>())
    .List<SiteWithWindowsTimezoneId>();

return activeSites;
```

--- The Resulting query ---

```
SELECT sa1_.Site_Key as y0_, 
    sa1_.Site_Id as y1_, 
    sa1_.Site_Id_Formatted as y2_, 
    sa1_.Site_Description as y3_, 
    swcfg2_.SiteWFCfg_Windows_Timezone_Id as y4_ 
FROM Sites_WF_Info this_ 
inner join Sites sa1_ 
    on this_.SiteWFInfo_Site_Key=sa1_.Site_Key 
inner join Profit_Centers pca3_ 
    on sa1_.Site_Key=pca3_.ProfCtr_Site_Key 
left outer join Sites_WF_Configuration swcfg2_ 
    on sa1_.Site_Key=swcfg2_.SiteWFCfg_Site_Key 
WHERE this_.SiteWFInfo_Effective_Date <= @p0 
    and @p1 <= this_.SiteWFInfo_End_Date 
    and pca3_.ProfCtr_Open_Date <= @p2 
    and @p3 < coalesce(pca3_.ProfCtr_Close_Date, @p4) 
    and this_.SiteWFInfo_TimeCapRule_Key > @p5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I do understand correctly, we need to replace the `left` *(currently property projection)* with the `effDate` constant projection. Then we can do it like this

```
// instead of this
// var left = Projections.Property<DateTime>(effDate);

// we would use this
// DateTime effDate is passed in
var effDate = DateTime.Today.Date; // C#'s today
var left = Projections.Constant(effDate);
```

And also, we should switch *(change the order)* of our "COALESCE", because the property should go first: Coalesce(ProfCtr_Close_Date, '6/6/2079')

```
var right = Projects.SqlFunction("COALESCE",
    NHibernateUtil.DateTime,

    // As DOC of COALESCE says:
    // "Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of 
    //  the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL."

    Projections.Property<ProfitCenter>(pc => pc.CloseDate), 
    Projections.Constant(DateTime.Parse("6/6/2079").DateNHibernateUtil.DateTime)
    );
```

Finally, we should use the same alias for the joined columns. Let's adjust main query a bit:

```
var foo = CurrentSession().QueryOver<Site>(() => sa)
    .Inner.JoinQueryOver<ProfitCenter>(() =>  sa.ProfitCenter, () => pca)
    .Where(restriction)
```

And the right side should use `pca` as well

```
var right = Projects.SqlFunction("COALESCE",
    NHibernateUtil.DateTime,
    // be sure that column goes to correct table
    // ==> use the same alias
    Projections.Property(() => pca.CloseDate), 
    Projections.Constant(DateTime.Parse("6/6/2079").DateNHibernateUtil.DateTime)
    );
```

Comment: Projections.Constant! Thank you. I updated my SQL query above to now include the SiteWorkforceInfo table. This one is a little squirrely because the Site Domain model doesn't reference SiteWorkforceInfo(s) in the same way that it references Profit Centers. Currently, I am trying to build the query starting from the SiteWorkforceInfo entity.

Comment: In case, that `SiteWorkforceInfo` is not referenced by Site Domain... it would hardly work. The reason is, that NHibernate can do JOIN **only** related to settings in the mapping. Other words, we cannot create any other JOIN than those coming from relations *(many-to-one, one-to-many)* defined in our mapping. But would that really be an issue to simply extend the model? and create such reference?

Comment: working on it...the 'boss' prefers not introducing additional 'temp' models into the Core...this one's getting longer ;)

Comment: Anyhow, good luck with NHibernate. Trust me, it is awesome tool. And if later anything... ask here on SO;) Enjoy NHiberante, sir!

Comment: Aaaaaaaaand, success! Turns out we introduced a new ResultModel namespace in our Core and have developed a new pattern for the team.